# How can I create per user usage reporting?

Tags: linux, memory, reporting, cpu, usage-statistics

I'm looking into ways to create monthly usage reporting on a per user basis. We would, ideally, like to include information such as cpu, memory, disk space, and network usage. I'm thinking since this is going to be a monthly report taking an average of both cpu and memory usage would be best. Disk space would be the size of all files owned by that user (most likely), and network usage would be the amount of bandwidth for that user (don't know if that is even possible). Does anybody have any suggestions on how to accomplish this? I've been looking for quite some time and have been unable to figure anything out. At this point any suggestions are good (tools that already exist, writing a script, etc.) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use command such as top(for CPU, memory), du -h (for disk usage), etc on a regular basis using any monitoring tools like [SeaLion](http://www.sealion.com), [New Relic](http://www.newrelic.com), [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org), etc

**New Relic** lets you plot graphs based on these metrics if you would like to present it in the form of graphs with respect to time. It also has many other features you could use.

Since you are trying to provide the average, I would suggest **SeaLion** which gives raw data, allowing you to download the data for the period that you require and then "grep" on it to calculate the average for these metrics.
Choose based on your requirement.